# Python tree structure

Tags: python, linux, unix, tree-structure

I am trying to create a tree structure for a repository holding multiple folders using python. I know that it is traditionally done through Linux or Unix.

My question is, are there any modules I can use to achieve this easily. Or a function already created? I have attached an image to give a better understanding of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `os.walk(<your root directory>)` ?

Comment: https://github.com/yoyzhou/pyTree

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am the new to programming and was asked by team to do this. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

this is an example,you can use the 'os ' library

```
import os
Path='project'

fout=open('path.txt','w')
for Name in os.listdir(Path) :
   Pathname= os.path.join(Path,Name)
   print>>fout,Pathname
fout.close()
```